# Google AutoML Ruby Gem Tables: Invalid String to assign to submessage field ''

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, google-cloud-automl

I'm trying to use the AutoML prediction service from the Ruby gem `google-cloud-automl` and I keep getting errors. I already have a deployed model working with the online predictions.

Here is my current code:

```
payload = {
  row: {
    column_spec_ids: %w(COLUMN_NUMBER_1 COLUMN_NUMBER_2 COLUMN_NUMBER_3 COLUMN_NUMBER_4),
    values: [
      DATA_1,
      DATA_2,
      DATA_3,
      DATA_4
    ]
  }
}

client = Google::Cloud::AutoML::Prediction.new(version: :v1beta1)
response = client.predict(formatted_model_path, payload)
```

and I receive this error:

```
Google::Protobuf::TypeError: Invalid type String to assign to submessage field ''.
from path/to/my/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/google-gax-1.8.1/lib/google/gax/util.rb:65:in `initialize'
```

(In my code, COLUMN_NUMBER_1 to _4 are actually real ID ant DATA_1 to _4 are strings)
`formatted_model_path` is the path of my model. I was able to access an NLP model earlier with this code (I only updated the payload format)

I've already tried to generate a Google::Cloud::AutoML::V1beta1::Row . I'm able to fill the column_spec_ids but every time I try this code

```
request = Google::Cloud::AutoML::V1beta1::Row.new
request.values = payload[:row][:values]
```

I get this error

```
Google::Protobuf::TypeError: Expected repeated field array
from (pry):4:in `method_missing'
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the solution...

You need to provide the kind of data you are passing.
Instead of

```
values: [
      DATA_1,
      DATA_2,
      DATA_3,
      DATA_4
    ]
```

I should have

```
values: [
      {string_value: DATA_1},
      {string_value: DATA_2},
      {string_value: DATA_3},
      {string_value: DATA_4}
    ]
```

(and you can have string_value, number_value and some other kind, i think the full list is [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf?&_ga=2.83721302.-1532970742.1573064538#google.protobuf.Value))